# Having issues parsing time with ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, format

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("946AM", "hmmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there something wrong here? I have tried several different variations of the format, but this is the one I'd expect to work.

Thanks

Comment: Eww, your fields are run together.  Note that [the "h" specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier) is not fixed-width... you're going to have some serious trouble with your lack of separators.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's what we have coming in. Think I'd be better off just inserting some separators in there? We could have 1035AM, 237PM, 1345, 120245PM, etc all that I'd have to deal with.

Comment: Yes... I think you could use a regular expressions to match and fix the data before parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) contains the following note in the remarks section:

> If *format* is a custom format pattern that does not include date or time separators (such as "yyyyMMdd HHmm"), use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

You are indeed lacking separators.  Worse, your data uses at least one variable-width field -- it is likely that you will need to write some of the parsing logic yourself or at least sanitize the data before passing it to `ParseExact`